# CSS issue - Style class doesn't show up in Chrome console

Tags: html, css

I have a stylesheet in my web application, and I created a class to change link colors and behaviors:

```
.lnk a, .lnk a:visited {
   color: #fff !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

.lnk a:hover {
   color: cornsilk;
}
```

And in the page itself, I use this markup:

```
View our <a href="terms.aspx" class="lnk">Terms & Conditions of Service</a>
```

There are a number of other styles in that same stylesheet (such as everything to style the navbar and so on), and they all work.  But for some weird reason, when I load the page, not only is the style for the link class not applied, it doesn't even show up when I inspect the elements in the Chrome developer console (although other elements of the page show CSS styles being applied from that same stylesheet).
I thought the "!important" declaration would help to override any other style(s) being applied, but it doesn't seem to help.  Any help here as to why?

Comment: `.lnk a` means you are targeting an `a` tag inside an element with class `.lnk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `a` tag inside class `lnk` which is not there. As you have applied the class to `a` tag, you can directly target `lnk`. You don't have to use `link a`. Check the snippet below.

```css
.lnk, .lnk:visited {
   color: red !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

.lnk:hover {
   color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
View our <a href="terms.aspx" class="lnk">Terms & Conditions of Service</a>
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I missed that!!!! (lol)  Too many late hours and not enough strong coffee...Thank you.

Comment: Take a coffee and relax. Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

You are using wrong query to select the element
it should be `a.lnk` which meant element `a` with class `lnk`
where as you did `.lnk a` which means element `a` which has it's parent element with class `lnk`

```html
<div class="lnk">
  <a href="/">click</a> <!-- this is .lnk a-->
</div>
```

Solution:

```css
a.lnk , a.lnk:visited {
   color: #CCC;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a.lnk:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
```

```html
View our <a href="terms.aspx" class="lnk">Terms & Conditions of Service</a>
```

**PS:**
Avoid using `!important` it can introduce behaviour which are unexpected.
In this case you used `!important` in `a.lnk` so even if you are changing color on `hover` it won't be changed as `!important` in `a.lnk` will override color in `hover` .

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is wrong; when you use a space it indicated a descendent (child) HTML element.  To fix this us the HTML and the class together `a.lnk` or JUST the class. `.lnk` - loose the `!important` - most of the time when you must use that you are doing something wrong.

Here I added some HMTL and CSS just to illustrate better given you color choice.

```css
.my-link-thing {
  border: solid blue 2px;
  background-color: #7777ff;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #77ff77;
}

a.lnk,
a.lnk:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.lnk:hover {
  color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<div>And in the page itself, I use this markup:
</div>
<div class="my-link-thing">
  View our <a href="terms.aspx" class="lnk"><span>Terms & Conditions of Service</span></a>
</div>
```